# Data binding with a ListBox in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I have tried to bind a ListBox items to a Grid.

In the Grid there is an Image and TextBlock.

I have successfully bound the TextBlock but I can't bind the image.

Whenever I click on a ListBox item the other TextBlocks are showing the result but I can't see the image.

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ExtraTemplate1}" ItemsSource="{Binding Extras}" Margin="46,127,0,129" Width="200"/>
    <Grid Margin="261,127,32,129" DataContext="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=listBox}">
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="29" Margin="0,0,20,8" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Price}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="94"/>
        <TextBlock Margin="167,14,20,41" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Description}"/>
        <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="8,14,0,41" Width="143" Source="{Binding Image}"/>
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are either providing a wrong value as the `Image` property of your model object (it should be a valid URI to the image) or your URI points to an unsupported image type (Silverlight 4 supports jpg and png). Try checking out the output window in VS during runtime to get more info about binding errors.

Answer (score 0):

Image Url should be like `/{projectname};component/{Folderpath}/imagename`

or take other image control add image source and take reference from that image source to set value of your Image Field in the list. Thanks